# Naming Aggregation Functions with Multiple Arguments (GroupBy)

Tags: python, pandas

In the object that results from aggregating data in the `GroupBy` object in pandas, the column headers are the name of the aggregation function. As is known in order to have to control over the column names a list of (name, function) tuples can be passed with .agg

Does anyone know how a similar control over the heading names can be had when passing user defined functions? For example:

```
#function to return max value minus min value
def MinMaxFunc(x):
    return np.max(x) - np.min(x)

DFGrouped = DF.groupby(key)
DFGrouped.agg([('Max_Minus_Min', MinMaxFunc)])
```

This works as expected. However, with a UDF with multiple arguments things are different:

```
#function to return sum of values adjusted for some percentage
def PCFunc(x, PCT_Val):
    return np.sum(x) * PCT_Val

# Pass function in regular manner
DFGrouped.agg(PCFunc, 0.2)
#Pass function so as to rename headers in resulting object
DFGrouped.agg([("Adjusted Sum", PCFunc, 0.2)])
```

This does not work, generating a `too many values to unpack` error.

One work around is to wrap the PCFunc in a lambda instead:

```
DFGrouped.agg([("AdjustedSum", lambda x: PCFunc(x, 0.2))])
```

But that seems annoying.

So the question finally: is there a way to pass (name, function) tuples when using `agg` with UDFs that have multiple arguments without wrapping the function in a `lambda`??